# Sending friend request to another facebook user programmatically - from iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to send friend request to another facebook user programmatically - from iphone sdk ?? (using facebook api for iphone)

for example:

in application, user(A) can send friend request to user(B) for facebook add as a friend, reading profile info and reading / writing on wall is something usual , but sending friend request programmatically is something different. and i also want to get facebook friend request status programmatically, whether another user accepted or rejected my friend request.

this all i want to do from an iphone application.

any good suggestion or idea will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can get a list of pending friend requests (subject to the user explicitly granting that permission), you can't programatically issue friend requests. You'll need to use the graph API for the former.